# Get values from same element

Tags: jquery, foreach

Looping trough some values. I got now like 8 paragraphs.

```
@foreach (var child in element.Childs)
{
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@child.Id" class="form-control">
        <input type="text" name="Name" value="@child.Name" class="form-control">
    </p>
}
```

When i press enter i want to call a page, but i need the id and a name.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p input').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Category/Update',
                data: {
                    'id': ID_VALUE,
                    'name': $(this).val()
                }   
            });
        }
    });
});
```

When i press enter on a textbox, how do i get the right id? So i need to get the value from id inside the same paragraphs.

Comment: Use the `id` property: `this.id`. Note that none of your elements have `id` attributes though.

Comment: None of the elements in your example have an ID property.

Comment: Would `$(this).find('#id').val()` do it?

Answer (score 0):

Change your input field to this:

```
<input type="text" name="Name" id="@child.id" value="@child.Name" class="form-control">
```

and then use this in your ajax call:

```
      $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Category/Update',
            data: {
                'id': this.id,
                'name': $(this).val()
            }   
        });
```

and you can delete your hidden field (unless it serves some other purpose!)